# Why is is_copy_constructible_v<vector<unique_ptr<T>> true?

Tags: c++, move, type-traits

A `vector` of `unique_ptr`s is obviously not copyable as proved by the code snippet below. The corresponding trait of `is_copy_constructible` returns true dispite of this. Why is that?

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

// This static assert passes, which is surprising
static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible_v<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>>);

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>
test(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>& original)
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> copy /* = original */;
    // commented-out part does not compile, as expected
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: I fixed the title of the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @MSalters that's probably why I didn't find it first.